# Call Property based on a string of its name

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I need to call a public property of a class based on the string value of its name, as I won't know until run time what properties are required. I'm trying to use reflections unsuccessfully.  The class looks like this:

```
class FieldCalculation
{
    public string MyValue
    {
        get
        {
            return "Test Data";
        }
    }
}
```

I think access the value of the property should look something like this:

```
FieldCalculation myClass = new FieldCalculation();
string value = myClass.GetType().GetProperty("MyValue");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Yes, I guess it's a duplicate. But I did find it useful separating out the definition of the FieldCalculation class as I didn't realize that was what had to be passed into the GetValue method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You nearly had it. What you were doing was getting the *property definition*. You need to ask that property to get you the value, and you pass it the instance. This is the working code:

```
FieldCalculation myClass = new FieldCalculation();
string value = (string)myClass.GetType().GetProperty("MyValue").GetValue(myClass);
```